# A Narnian mole based on a British admiral?

Tags: name-significance, c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia

[Clodsley Shovel](https://narnia.fandom.com/wiki/Clodsley_Shovel): a talking mole who plays a minor role in *Prince Caspian*.

[Cloudesley Shovell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudesley_Shovell): a British admiral who died off the Isles of Scilly.

What's going on here? Did Lewis ever acknowledge the connection or give a reason why? Is there any thematic reason why this mole character would be named after a long-dead navy admiral?

Comment: This is a joke! A mole digs earth, that is, it shovels clods.

Comment: @GarethRees That's what I always assumed, just a random moley-sounding name, but just today I learned about the admiral and surely it's not a coincidence.

Comment: Right, so if you were familiar with the admiral, as Lewis surely was, then you might think to yourself, "that would make a good name for a mole".

Comment: And then there's this line in the Wikipedia article:  "Shovell's body was identified by the purser of the third-rate HMS Arundel, who knew the admiral well. It was identified by 'a black mole under his left ear...' "  The joke seems to be many-faceted.